# Resetting admin user details

Tags: users, 8

I forgot my drupal admin password and tried resetting it using forgot password option, but it fails to work( does not send the mail).

Drupal 8 is installed on my localhost. I tried manually editing the users table in the database, so I deleted the user with uid 1(admin) and also deleted corresponding data for uid 1 from users_field_data table.

I am unable to figure out the value to be inserted for uuid in users table. I tried giving 1 for uid, my_name for uuid and md5(password), but the login fails. uuid seems to be encrypted somehow and i can't figure how.

Also, I am using wamp, so I haven't tried using drush or drupal console for version 8.

I found two relevant answers on topics " Insert “uuid” in “users” and Is there a good and recent documentation on the UUID API in Drupal 8 core? ", but not of much help.

Comment: I highly doubt that you forgot your password, maybe the login form is not working properly. Take a look at my answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206084/after-restoring-a-site-from-backup-forms-dont-do-anything/206098#answer-206098) this may possibly be your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily manually insert a user record. The password is not an MD5 hash, it a salted SHA-256 hash.

You hopefully made a backup, you should restore that. From there, you should consider to use [drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/), which is the by-far easiest way to log in, with drush uli to generate a one-time login link or drush upwd, to set the password of a user.