# Cannot log in to Drupal running alongside WordPress multi-site

Tags: 7, users, sessions

I have a Drupal site (7) that I've migrated to a new server. I have a WordPress multi-site install on this server that looks like this at the moment:

- example.com
- store.example.com

I used to have a forum.example.com, but frankly the available WordPress forum options leave a lot to be desired, so I moved my old Drupal forum instead of migrating.

The issue is that I cannot log in to Drupal, from any account, even using a Drush generated link.

I've tried clearing caches, truncating session tables, adding `$base_url` in the settings.php file, setting session.name on both the WordPress and Drupal installations.
I'm at a loss. I've been banging my head against this for 4 hours now. I switched to a secondary domain (forum.example2.com) and it works perfectly; so all I can come up with is that there is some sort of collision between the two frameworks with either the sessions or the cookies.

Why cannot I log in with any account? How can I fix this?

Edit:
To be clear, if I change Apache to point a different domain to this installation, everything works fine. I installed Flarum in place of drupal, and am able to log in. This problem is only present when the two frameworks are drupal and WordPress, and they are subdomains of the same main domain

Setting the user manually also doesn't work, for example:

```
global $user;
if(ip_address() == 'my.ip.address'){
   $user = user_load(1);
}
```

If I dump the user object after this it is loaded, but the next page load still leaves my as an anonymous user.

Comment: are both the wordpress and drupal files on the same directory then? if not, how are you separating them on the server and dns?

Comment: Did you enable [a2enmod rewrite](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206084/after-restoring-a-site-from-backup-forms-dont-do-anything/206098#answer-206098)?

Comment: Do messages appear or is anything logged when login fails? Have you tried clearing your browser cookies for the problem domain?

Comment: They are in their own directories, there is a wildcard dns entry, Apache has a wildcard directive and a forums directive.

Comment: Mod rewrite is enabled, I have cleared browsing history and cookies, and tested on a different machine that has never accessed this site.

Comment: There are no messages, according to the watchdog the session is started, but the login page just reloads.... Actually, if I point to a page with access restrictions there is a login form, so after login it just reloads, if I start at the "user" page, it takes me to the user/1 page, but I'm still not logged in.

Comment: @kiamlaluno the title was specific because I can log in if it's on a different domain, I can also log in to a different framework in the same setup. So this isn't just a login problem, it's a problem when drupal and WordPress muli-site are both on the same domain.

Comment: what is your COOKIE_DOMAIN in wp-config.php ?

Comment: Currently it's commented out, I had set it as .forum.mydomain.com (where mydomain is my actual domain).

I've also just discovered that adding an exit at the beginning of includes/sessions.inc doesn't exit.

Comment: my mistake, I don't have a cooke domain set in wp_config

Comment: I found the problem, I was using the APDQC module on the old site and hadn't disabled it, not sure why, but it was the source of my issue. After disabling it the problem is gone.

Comment: @Trey Most likely the issue is colliding apache configuraion. If it's only for a specific domain you experience issues it points to the issue being located in the webserver configuration as Drupal doesn't care about domains. My best bet is that you have some config for `forum.example.com` later in the apache config which overwrites what config you made for the Drupal site. The exeption would be if you used something like the Domain module suite where domain name will have an effect, but for a Forum site that doesn't sound likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should disable APDQC module on the old site.

The above was the answer given in comments. If the voting system requires you to choose a winner, I'm not above a simple comment repost answer :D

Comment: Lol you win this one

Answer (score 0):

I bet it was the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` in wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'sub.mydomain.com');
```

Define it without leading dot.

Comment: It was not, it was a module I forgot to disable